# How can I create a second instagram account?

Tags: instagram

I want to create a second instagram account. I already have my personal instagram, and I want to create a second one for an art project.

For the art project, I'm not necessarily planning on using my phone to upload the pictures, instead I'd use a web browser based client like [Gramfeed.](http://www.gramfeed.com/)

However for that I'll still need the existing account. How can I do that?

Comment: can't you just log out your personal IG account and register as a new user from the instagram app..?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if multiple account signup is currently supported in Instagram mobile app and sign up is not available except through the website. There was once single phone can create only single account restriction. If you are unable to create a new account from your mobile app and if you dont have two phones, then the only way to create a new instagram account in a computer is to

Install [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com) or [Andy](http://andyroid.net/) Emulator for computer -> Install Instagram App -> Create a new account.

And access the created account in a browser or in the emulator itself.

If you have a Lollipop OS you don't need two phone nor need to setup Bluestacks. You can install Instagram app under two different User Accounts and both Instagram apps share a different appdata and therefore different username to login with.

Comment: Unfortunately Bluestack is a PITA and slow to use. I've tried, and I don't recommend this solution.

Comment: @dwjohnston if your computer runs Bluestacks laggy..then try Andy emulator..but If your RAM is too less that wont help either..but, If you have a lollipop OS, you dont need to install an emulator at all.  see my updated answer